# How to pass Base64 encoded image to WCF REST endpoint

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I am attempting to select an image on my computer and pass the data to a REST endpoint using the file element.

`<input type="file" id="input">`

I am able to render the image and display it in the browser. However, I get an empty string or object when passing the image to the endpoint as shown in the code below.

```
(function () {

const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");

inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function() {

            return function(e) {
                sendFile(e.target.result);
            };

        })();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }


function sendFile(file) {

    let img = {
        'Photo': new Blob([file], {type : 'image/png'})
    };

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/example/service.svc/AddPhoto/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(img));

}})();
```

Service looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddPhoto/", Method = "POST", 
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = 
     WebMessageFormat.Json)]
     void AddPhoto(BlogEntityModel blogEntityModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the file as JSON, you have to take into account two things:

- The value of `e.target.result` is a data URI.
- You cannot convert Blob to JSON using the `stringify` method.

So, to fix it, you just should replace `'Photo': new Blob([file], {type : 'image/png'})` with `'Photo': file`.

Keep in mind that in your case, the variable `file` is a data URI. If you want to submit only the Base64 value you have to remove the `data:image/xxx;base64,` prefix.

Comment: Okay, it is working now, I replaced this: `data:image/xxx;base64,` and parse the remaining data as a string but converted to bytes[] before inserting in the database.